# How can I stylize the text of a button or toggle button in JavaFX using CSS?

Tags: java, css, stylesheet, javafx-8

I'm not sure this is even possible. I've looked around on google a bit and found next to nothing on this subject. I like being able to stylize labels to make them look engraved or embossed in the CSS style sheet using the InnerShadow and DropShadow effects. I've tried the same on buttons but it doesn't effect the text, it just applies it directly to the button.

What would be the CSS I would need to use to apply the InnerShadow and/or DropShadow effects to the text of a button or toggle button?

Comment: [See FXExperience: Styling FX Buttons with CSS](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/)

Comment: @jewelsea
I checked this but it's old and its about JavaFX 2, not JavaFX 8. I tried some of what they have in there but it doesn't seem to carry over. Like #ID Text with fx-effect drop shadow, has no effect.

Comment: You can determine classes and ids for CSS selectors using either the [ScenicView tool](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) or the [SceneBuilder CSS analyzer](https://blogs.oracle.com/jeromec/entry/using_the_new_css_analyzer); I recommend them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Om further comments in the [FXExperience: Styling FX Buttons with CSS](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/) page, it is mentioned that
the `#ID Text` has been changed to `#ID LabeledText`. I just confirmed that on JavaFX 8.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to add a label into your button and stylize your label

Comment: A pretty good idea but if there is solution that does not require adding labels i'd rather go with that.

Comment: Button already extends Labeled.  As can be seen in the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled), a Label has no more CSS properties than Labeled, so that means that there are no additional CSS properties that would apply to a Button with a Label added to it than would apply to a Button alone: "The ButtonBase control has all the properties of Labeled".